# ASMX Javascript proxy using different host headers

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, sharepoint, asmx

I am using an ASMX service in my app and would like it to point to a particular web service URL.

I have defined it as below:

```
string serviceUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/_vti_bin/MyService.asmx";

ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);

if (scriptManager != null) scriptManager.Services.Add(new ServiceReference(serviceUrl));
else
{
    scriptManager = new ScriptManager();
    scriptManager.Services.Add(new ServiceReference(serviceUrl));

    Page.Form.Controls.Add(scriptManager);
}
```

Here `SPContext.Current.Web.Url ==> http://mysite/mysubsite`

But when I invoke the service from Javascript like below, host header inspection in the Firebug suggests that the Javascript proxy is actually calling the service at: `http://mysite/_vti_bin/MyService.asmx/Execute`

```
MyWorkCore.API.Execute("GetData", dataXml, function (response) {
    // doing something here
});
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the reason for your problem, but I belive you may be pointing to the wrong location for the asmx. The "_vti_bin" folder is a folder that frontpage extensions creates. The asmx file should reside in a root of the site or in a folder structure within the root of the web site. It should not reside in the bin or "_vti_bin".

Comment: @Alex Mendez: All SharePoint services reside in _vti_bin

Comment: I never worked with sharepoint so, was not aware of this. Thanks for the info. At the moment, I cannot think of anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You specified server relative path, as I see it. Try using and resolving the path like this:

```
~site/_vti_bin/MyService.asmx
```

In SPUtility class there a function that resolves such prefixed paths with prefixes "~site" (resolved to current SPWeb url) and "~sitecollection" that resolved to current SPSite URL.

Here "current" means SPContext.Current.Site for SPSite and SPContext.Current.Web for SPWeb.